# Is it possible to create a dynamic directive in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let me first post the explanation of what I am trying to accomplish with broken-pseudocode:

```
// controllers.js
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', [function() {
     var template = '<div my-directive></div>';
     var div = $("#view1").append(template);
     var code = http.get('/dynamic-code-for-directive');
     angular.module('myApp.directives').directive(eval(code));

  }])

// Index.html
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a id="view1" href="#/view1">view1</a></li>       
  </ul>
</body>
</html>

// code.js returned by "GET /dynamic-code-for-directive"
function(scope, element){ $("#view1").append("Hello World");
```

### Explanation

Basically I want the server to provide the definition for the directive, and then generate one on the fly.
The problem, it seems, is with the `append` call above --- it does not recognize the template  as the directive, so the directive code never gets called.

Has anyone ever tried to accomplish anything similar to this?

Comment: Please, select best answer if you got your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

try doing it in the following order

```
 var code = http.get('/dynamic-code-for-directive');
 angular.module('myApp.directives').directive(eval(code)); //ie adding the directive definition
```

then make a template but one step that you are missing is COMPILING it

```
     $scope.template = $compile(<div my-directive></div>')($scope);
```

then append it!

```
angular.element("#view1").append($scope.template);
```

please revert back with the results

Comment: Where do I get the `$compile` from? I.e. I can't inject it into controller for some reason.

Comment: your controller also has $scope missing in it write [function($scope,$compile)]

Comment: I did, but `$compile` is undefined at that point. Does it require some kind of module dependency, do you know?

Comment: look out for different ways of defining your module i am sure there is  something wrong in the way you are defining your angular module.Controllers have access to $compile or it can also be an issue with your angular js version please upgrade to the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

There is some things you are doing wrong, you are doing DOM manipulation inside a controller, which is wrong and not an appropriate use of angularjs.

To use $compile you need to be inside a directive. It would look something like:

```
app.directive('directiveCreator', function($compile, $http) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var template = '<div my-directive></div>';
    element.html(template);
    var code = $http.get('/dynamic-code-for-directive');
    app.directive('myDirective', function() {
       var link = eval(code);
      return {
        link : link
      }
    }
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
  }
  );
};
```

There might be mistakes but it would be something like that.

Comment: So I need a directive to create a directive? :-) But I don't know ahead of time how many directives there will be! Hm...I'll have to give it more thought.

Comment: But I don't know ahead of time how many directives I will need. So I will need `directiveCreator1`, `directiveCreator2`, etc.. But if I need to create THESE directives dynamically, I am back to square one: how do I create directives on the fly?

Comment: You only need one directiveCreator. What does tell you how many directives you need?

Comment: The server will. For example, imagine application with dynamic number of tabs at the top. Clicking on the tab fetches a dynamic template and a "directive" that will know how to handle the html in that template. So, one template may contain, say a table (with sorting and other custom behavior), while another --- some sort of form. The point is that each tab's content would be defined via a template dynamically loaded from the server, and it's behavior --- by a dynamically loaded code (which I was thinking would be possible to write as a directive). Hope this is not too confusing!